# How to access domain-specific routes on a local development environment?

Tags: php, laravel

In `web.php` I have something like this, along with the usual routes.

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'sub.example.com'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'MyController@home')->name('home');
});
```

If I go to `localhost`, the browser directs me to the usual routes. How do I get to these domain specific ones? My current solution is to add an entry in the hosts file. Is there another solution that doesn't involve editing the hosts file?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your hosts file for with sudomain

Sa
127.0.0.1 sub.example.com